# Spring MVC and Thymeleaf Prevent Entity Id Leak

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have `Demand` entity. I can update my entity without any problem but I think my approch have some security problem.

**demandController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateDemand(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute Demand demand, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "demandUpdateForm";

    } else {
        demand.setDemandId(id);
        demandService.updateDemand(demand);
        return "redirect:/demands";
    }
}
```

**serviceImpl**

```
@Override
public Demand updateDemand(Demand demand) {
    return demandRepository.save(demand);
}
```

**form**

```
 <form id="vendorForm" th:action="@{/demands/details/__${demand.demandId}__}" th:object="${demand}" method="post" >
```

As you see I get `DemandId` from action. For example I want to update 5th id's `demand` and get the update form. Then I changed `demandId` via developer tools and click submit. If I modify id for example 2nd and form update my 2nd id `demand` not original the 5th one. How can I prevent this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you create unmanaged bean for this operations and will pass it as form backing bean.

```
public class DemandBean {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    ...
    // more fields 
}
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateDemand(@Valid @ModelAttribute("demandBean") DemandBean demandBean, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "demandUpdateForm";
    } else {
        demandService.updateDemand(demandBean.getId(), demandBean.getName, ...);
        return "redirect:/demands";
    }
}
```

Service method :

```
@Override
public void updateDemand(Long id, String name, //etc) {
    Demand d = id == null ? new Demand() : demandRepository.findOne(id);
    d.setName(name);
    // ...
    // set other fields 
    return demandRepository.save(demand);
}
```

This approach helps you to avoid security leaks with passing `id`.

Comment: I have a lot of fields in my Demand entity like 15. Is there any easy way to set new values to fields?

Comment: My job to offer you, you decide what to do next :)